# #states attribute of FORM API?

Tags: javascript

Currently I am using **states** attribute in my form to show/hide a drodown having days as its value on selecting a parent dropdown value. My working scenerio is that I want to show a dropdown having 31 days if january,march,may.... is selected and to show another dropdown having 30 days as its value when febraury,april,june .... is selected , can some one suggest me how its could be achieved because in usage of #states attribute only one value could be selected.

function sandbox_ajax_dropdown($form, &$form_state) {

```
$options = array(1 => t('1 月'), 2 => t('2 月'), 3 => t('3 月'), 4 => t('4 月'), 5 => t('5 月'), 6 => t('6 月'), 7 => t('7 月'), 8 => t('8 月'), 9 => t('9 月'), 10 => t('10 月'), 11 => t('11 月'), 12 => t('12 月'),);

$form['state_list'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => 'Choose A Day First',
    '#options' => $options
);
$form['illinois_cities'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#description' => t("Thirty-One Days."),
    '#states' => array(
        'visible' => array(
            ':input[name="state_list"]' => array('value' => '5'),
        ),
    ),
    '#options' => array(1 => t('1'), 2 => t('2'), 3 => t('3'), 4 => t('4'), 5 => t('5'), 6 => t('6'), 7 => t('7'), 8 => t('8'), 9 => t('9'), 10 => t('10'), 11 => t('11'), 12 => t('12'),
        13 => t('13'), 14 => t('14'), 15 => t('15'), 16 => t('16'), 17 => t('17'), 18 => t('18'), 19 => t('19'), 20 => t('20'), 21 => t('21'), 22 => t('22'), 23 => t('23'), 24 => t('24'),
        25 => t('25'), 26 => t('26'), 27 => t('27'), 28 => t('28'), 29 => t('29'), 30 => t('30'), 31 => t('31')),
);

$form['ohio_cities'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#description' => t("Thirty Days."),
    '#states' => array(
        'visible' => array(
            ':input[name="state_list"]' => array('value' => '1', '2'),
        ),
    ),
    '#options' => array(1 => t('1'), 2 => t('2'), 3 => t('3'), 4 => t('4'), 5 => t('5'), 6 => t('6'), 7 => t('7'), 8 => t('8'), 9 => t('9'), 10 => t('10'), 11 => t('11'), 12 => t('12'),
        13 => t('13'), 14 => t('14'), 15 => t('15'), 16 => t('16'), 17 => t('17'), 18 => t('18'), 19 => t('19'), 20 => t('20'), 21 => t('21'), 22 => t('22'), 23 => t('23'), 24 => t('24'),
        25 => t('25'), 26 => t('26'), 27 => t('27'), 28 => t('28'), 29 => t('29'), 30 => t('30'))
);

return $form;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Found it !!!!!!!!
The solution is below highlighted.

function modulename_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

```
if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_14209') {

    $form['submitted']['dob'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('出生日期'),
        '#weight' => 4,
    );

    $form['submitted']['dob']['dob_month'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('月'),
        '#options' => array(
            1 => t('1 月'), 2 => t('2 月'), 3 => t('3 月'), 4 => t('4 月'), 5 => t('5 月'), 6 => t('6 月'), 7 => t('7 月'), 8 => t('8 月'), 9 => t('9 月'), 10 => t('10 月'), 11 => t('11 月'), 12 => t('12 月'),
        ),
        '#description' => t('Select month.'),
        '#required' => true,
    );

    /* for 31 days */
    $form['submitted']['dob']['dob_day_31'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('日'),
        '#options' => array(1 => t('1'), 2 => t('2'), 3 => t('3'), 4 => t('4'), 5 => t('5'), 6 => t('6'), 7 => t('7'), 8 => t('8'), 9 => t('9'), 10 => t('10'), 11 => t('11'), 12 => t('12'),
            13 => t('13'), 14 => t('14'), 15 => t('15'), 16 => t('16'), 17 => t('17'), 18 => t('18'), 19 => t('19'), 20 => t('20'), 21 => t('21'), 22 => t('22'), 23 => t('23'), 24 => t('24'),
            25 => t('25'), 26 => t('26'), 27 => t('27'), 28 => t('28'), 29 => t('29'), 30 => t('30'), 31 => t('31')),
        '#description' => t("Thirty-One Days."),
        '#required' => true,
        ***'#states' => array(
            'visible' => array(
                ':input[name="submitted[dob][dob_month]"]' => array(
                    array('value' => '1'),
                    array('value' => '3'),
                    array('value' => '5'),
                    array('value' => '7'),
                    array('value' => '8'),
                    array('value' => '10'),
                    array('value' => '12'),
                ),
            ),***
        ),
    );

    /* for 30 days */
    $form['submitted']['dob']['dob_day_30'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('日'),
        '#options' => array(1 => t('1'), 2 => t('2'), 3 => t('3'), 4 => t('4'), 5 => t('5'), 6 => t('6'), 7 => t('7'), 8 => t('8'), 9 => t('9'), 10 => t('10'), 11 => t('11'), 12 => t('12'),
            13 => t('13'), 14 => t('14'), 15 => t('15'), 16 => t('16'), 17 => t('17'), 18 => t('18'), 19 => t('19'), 20 => t('20'), 21 => t('21'), 22 => t('22'), 23 => t('23'), 24 => t('24'),
            25 => t('25'), 26 => t('26'), 27 => t('27'), 28 => t('28'), 29 => t('29'), 30 => t('30')),
        '#description' => t("Thirty Days."),
        '#required' => true,
        '#states' => array(
            'visible' => array(
                ':input[name="submitted[dob][dob_month]"]' => array(
                    array('value' => '2'),
                    array('value' => '4'),
                    array('value' => '6'),
                    array('value' => '9'),
                    array('value' => '11'),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );

    $form['submitted']['dob']['dob_year'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('年'),
        '#options' => array(1 => t('2013'), 2 => t('2012'), 3 => t('2011'), 4 => t('2010'), 5 => t('2009'), 6 => t('2008'), 7 => t('2007'), 8 => t('2006'),
            9 => t('2005'), 10 => t('2004'), 11 => t('2003'), 12 => t('2002'), 13 => t('2001'), 14 => t('2000'), 15 => t('1999'), 16 => t('1998'), 17 => t('1997'),
            18 => t('1996'), 19 => t('1995'), 20 => t('1994'), 21 => t('1993'), 22 => t('1992'), 23 => t('1991'), 24 => t('1990'), 25 => t('1989'), 26 => t('1988'),
            27 => t('1987'), 28 => t('1986'), 29 => t('1985'), 30 => t('1984'), 31 => t('1983'),
        ),
        '#description' => t('Select year.'),
        '#required' => true,
    );
}
return $form;
```

}